# Has anyone implemented a recognition algorithm for totally unimodular matrices?

Tags: matrices, matroid-theory, total-unimodularity

One of the consequences of Seymour's characterization of regular matroids is the existence of a polynomial time recognition algorithm for totally unimodular matrices (i.e. matrices for which every square sub-determinant is in {0, 1, -1}).

But has anyone actually implemented it?

Comment: I guess I'll take the silence as a probable "no"... 

It seems like something that I would like to have done, but don't actually want to do..

Comment: as of 2022, the algorithm is implemented in c++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT.** Walter and Trümper have [announced on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4061) their implementation, with source code available, of two methods for testing total unimodularity. Their paper describes the technical details of the implementation / algorithm, and also provides several experimental results.

---

I found the following link for an implementation in R, where they claim to have a function for testing whether a matrix is totally unimodular. I have not checked which particular algorithm they use.

Link: [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deducorrect/deducorrect.pdf)

Comment: The implementation mentioned already is available at [this site](http://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~walter/TUtest/). It is a C++ library with a straight-forward interface.

Comment: The link in @Xammy's comment is outdated. The C++ library can now be found [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~klaus/TUtest/).

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge no one has implemented the algorithm. A good reference though for someone thinking about it would be Truember's book "Matroid Decomposition" which contains a fairly simple description of the necessary steps.